# How can I pass multiple parameters through a React <select> component?

Tags: reactjs

Here is my `<select>` component:

```
handleSelect: function(myVar, anotherVar) {
  // Do I need to somehow use event.preventDefault(); here?
  // I want to be able to do something with myVar and anotherVar here...
  // ...but it seems I cannot access the event and the value of anotherVar
  // at the same time...at least not this way.
},
render: function() {
  let myVar = "Yes",
      anotherVar = "Another value",
      id = 1;
  return (
    <select defaultValue={myvar} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, anotherVar}>
      <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
      <option value="No">No</option>
    </select>
  );
}
```

I want to be able to work with `myVar` (based on the `<select>` input's value) and `anotherVar` in my `handleSelect` function. How do I properly pass the value of the `<select>` element in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to realize that the `event` is still passed when you use `bind` to pass a variable to a function like `handleSelect`.

I could use `onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, anotherVar}` in my `<select>` element and access the variables like this:

```
handleSelect: function(anotherVar, event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let myVar = event.target.value;
  ...rest of my code using myVar and anotherVar...
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Both vars should be states and defined in the constructor:

```
class FooComponent extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { myvar: 'foo', anotherVar : '' };
 }
 handleSelect(event){
     this.setState({anotherVar: event.target.value}, console.log('My var ' + this.state.myvar));
 }
 render(){
    return(
       <div>
           <select id="blabla" onChange={this.handleSelect.bind(this)} value={this.state.myvar}>
              <option value="select">Select</option>
              <option value="Java">Java</option>
              <option value="Ruby">Ruby</option>
           </select>
           <p></p>
           <p>{this.state.anotherVar}</p>
       </div>
    );
 }
```